# TinyMCE full screen mode in WordPress and obscuring elements

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, fullscreen

My [website](https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk) uses the TinyMCE 4 toolbar with Wordpress 5.2.4.

As you can see, it has a navigation menu:

[image: Navigation bar]

At the bottom it has a language bar:

[image: Language bar]

My TinyMCE toolbar is displayed when creating / editing bbPress forum topics and it has a **full screen** toggle:

[image: Full Screen toggle]

My problem is that when I go to full screen mode the main menu and language bar are still visible. Atleast, the menu should not be showing:

[image: Full screen mode]

How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gTranslate` wrapper has a `z-index` of `9999999` which is difficult to beat.

[image]

I would suggest you to lower this value under the Tiny Mce wrapper z-index value

## Update

New clarifications:

- The MCE Editor default `z-index` is `100010`.
- The MCE Editor pop-up windows `z-index` (like **Insert Image**) are `100100`.

So the `gTranslate` wrapper has to be below `100010`. In addition, the `main-navigation ul` index is too high too.

The following added to the **Additional CSS** section of the website resolves the issues:

```
div#gtranslate_wrapper {
    z-index: 100000 !important;
}

.main-navigation ul {
    z-index: 100000 !important;
}
```

This way, all elements are hidden but not the pop-up windows used by the MCE editor itself.